# any existing solutions for a subscription type of a store?

Tags: facebook, paypal-subscriptions, payment-processing

Is there an existing solution that provides the following?

- any seller can create a store with virtual products - every product costs a monthly subscription fee (the solution will contain many stores)
- any buyer can subscribe to products (set-up recurring payment)
- the system should be worldwide/universal for all types of payments - credit cards, paypal, ..., the system should also support mass payouts to the sellers

Is there an existing solution that I can use/buy? (can shopify or other services do this?)

If not - what components should I use while building such system? I was thinking about https://www.paypal.com/pdn-recurring along with paypal Payouts API, but what about the system for building the stores?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're the person creating the product and you want many sellers to sell your product and you want to give them a recurring payout when that happens.

If that's the case, have you looked into Affiliate systems like Clickbank or JvZoo, where you list your product with them and then affiliates will sell the product for you and they handle all the payment processing.

Paypal doesn't handle affiliate payouts, so it's going to a lot of work on your side to track and do payment disbursement and handle refunds and charge backs.

Comment: some clarifications - i'd like to build a marketplace - i.e. - other people create the products